# Using $_SESSION to carry data

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have attempted to use $_SESSION in a form input I am creating however I cannot get it to work and do not know what I am doing wrong, it works with my previous part of the form when carrying data over to the next page - however the code does not seem to work for the main part of the form.

```
    <?php

//This includes the variables, adjusted within the 'config.php file' and the functions from the 'functions.php' - the config variables are adjusted prior to anything else.
require('configs/config.php');
require('configs/functions.php');

//Check to see if the form has been submited, if it has we continue with the script.
if(isset($_POST['confirmation']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['address1']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['postcode']) and $_POST['confirmation']=='true')
{
    //Slashes are removed, depending on whether magic_quotes_gpc is on.
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_POST['name'] = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
        $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['address1'] = stripslashes($_POST['address1']);
        $_POST['address2'] = stripslashes($_POST['address2']);
        $_POST['city'] = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
        $_POST['postcode'] = stripslashes($_POST['postcode']);
        $_POST['phonenum'] = stripslashes($_POST['phonenum']);
    }

    //Create the future reference number of the repair.
    $maxid = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select max(id) as id from repairs'));
    $id = intval($maxid['id'])+1;

    //Create the future reference number of the repair.
    $maxref = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select max(reference) as reference from repairs'));
    $reference = intval($maxref['reference'])+8;

    //Here the session variables are converted back into standard variables.
    $model = $_SESSION['model'];
    $problem = $_SESSION['problem'];
    $info = $_SESSION['info'];
    $device = $_SESSION['device'];
    $price = $_SESSION['price'];
    $image = $_SESSION['image']; 

    //Here the variables are protected using mysql_real_escape_string.
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['name'],0,150));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['email'],0,255));
    $address1 = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['address1'],0,255));
    $address2 = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['address2'],0,255));
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['city'],0,100));
    $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['postcode'],0,9));
    $phonenum = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['phonenum'],0,11));
    $date = date("r");

    //Here the variables are protected using trim.
    $name = trim($name);
    $email = trim($email);
    $address1 = trim($address1);
    $address2 = trim($address2);
    $city = trim($city);
    $postcode = trim($postcode);
    $phonenum = trim($phonenum);

    //Here the variables are protected using htmlspecialchars.
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
    $address1 = htmlspecialchars($address1);
    $address2 = htmlspecialchars($address2);
    $city = htmlspecialchars($city);
    $postcode = htmlspecialchars($postcode);
    $phonenum = htmlspecialchars($phonenum);

    //Here the variables are protected using strip_tags.
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $address1 = strip_tags($address1);
    $address2 = strip_tags($address2);
    $city = strip_tags($city);
    $postcode = strip_tags($postcode);
    $phonenum = strip_tags($phonenum);

    //The details about the repair are entered into the database
    $query = mysql_query("insert into repairs (id, model, problem, info, name, email, address1, address2, city, postcode, phonenum, price, date, reference) values ('$id', '$model', '$problem', '$info', '$name', '$email', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$postcode', '$phonenum', '$price', '$date', '$reference')") or die(header('Location: 404.php'));
?>
```

Some HTML is here.

```
<?  
  }
  else {
     header('Location: 404.php');
  }
?>
```

Can anyone help me to get this to work?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `session_start()` anywhere.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` included on the page?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is not working here? the form? the form processing? the SQL? the session storing? And what kind of error you got?

If it's the session problem, remember you need to start session on top of your page session_start();

Comment: The session has already been called on a previous page and I have not unset or destroyed it, regardless even if it is called it makes no difference. Anyway the session seems to continue on the previous page without calling it.

Comment: session_start(); have to be on every page if you need to use it.

Comment: It has to be called on every page.

Comment: @Alex: You need to call `session_start()` on every page that wants to use the session.

Comment: Regardless even if it is called it makes no difference. Anyway the session seems to continue on the previous page without calling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to initiate your session in the beginning of your script with `session_start()`

Comment: I got it working in the end, the problem was I had accidentally (and stupidly) moved the script to another folder and I had not noticed. Also session_start(); does not need to be called on every page that is part of a single session.

Comment: True, if `session.auto_start` has been defined `true` in PHP configuration, then no. Even then, you should make a good habit to ALWAYS call it on every page at least for compatibility reasons. If a session exists, another `session_start()` will simply be ignored, so there's no reason not to do that. Also, you have two `require` lines in your code so I wonder how you've been able to move this script to another folder without noticing as it should cause fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR.`

Answer (score 1):

set your error logging to the most verbose level. If your Paste is exact, you have some spaces in the beginning which cause, that you cant send headers anymore and so you cant initiate the session.