# $_SESSION variable used to check if form has been submitted

Tags: php, html, post, session-variables

I have a landing page called `index.php' with the following form:

```
<form action="auto_mail.php" method="post">
   <input id="signup" class="span8" type="text" placeholder="Your email" name="signup">
   <input type="submit">
   <?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['got_it']))
     {echo "<b>You're all signed up!</b>}
   ?></form>
```

In the file `auto_mail.php` I have:

```
// code scrubbing user input...
$user_email = $_POST['signup'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['got_it'] = '1';
// code sending me an email when someone signs up.
echo <<<EOD
  </b>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0, url=index.php">
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
EOD;
?>
```

I've looked at some other SO questions ([Using $_SESSION to carry data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924338/using-session-to-carry-data)), but it's not what I'm looking for.

All I want, is for a user to see "You're all signed up" when they enter a valid email; with the email confirm email being sent in the background.  This code feels clumsy and awkward.  It also flashes the `auto_mail.php` page briefly.

I tried to set `<form action="index.php"...`, but it doesn't work because I've set up `auto_mail.php` such that you can't access it directly.

How can use the code in `auto_mail.php`, which checks for a valid email address and sends confirm emails, without dealing with both `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`, or at least using them better?

Comment: I use that kind of stuff to make my web sites login and it works just fine. I use ajax with jquery and the traditional reload also and both works.

Comment: Have you used session_start() on index.php ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to have any page reloads whatsoever, you'll have to use AJAX to send the form, instead of utilising the form `POST`.

If you are using jQuery, or Mootools, they both have built in wrappers to handle ajax calls. Without a helper library, you'll have to look into making an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) yourself.

Other than that, traditionally, you would redirect the user to a "form submitted" page, or *alternatively*, have the form `action` be sent to the same page (in your case, `index.php`, and have PHP code to handle form data if it is received).

Answer (score 0):

I dont get completely what you want.

I think you try to Verify a Mail Address (after?) that form has been sent. But you cannot access the file via http that does the verification.

Have you thought about including the auto_mail.php?

Comment: I tried use include, but I ended up just posting the HTML from auto_mail.php right along with the HTML from index.php.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should consider using one of popular PHP frameworks. I guess you didn't use any in above example. Good framework that also offers MVC structure allows to do operations like this in such a simple way you can't even imagine.

Breaking it down to MVC structure will even make it extremely simple to handle `post` sending and displaying dependences and results made by it in one action. 
Learing good framework at first might look like a waste of time, but believe me - it will pay off very quickly.

For start I recommend you looking at `Kohana Framework` or, if you're ambitions one - `Symfony Framework`.